# Error in jfrog-cli : The following error was received while trying to encrypt your password: Artifactory response: 404 404

Tags: jfrog-cli

Error in jfrog-cli : The following error was received while trying to encrypt your password

Comment: Please make sure your platform URL does not end with `/artifactory`. 
Respectfully, if you are providing Artifactory URL, make sure it ends with `/artifactory`.

Comment: Yes I did the same but it's giving an error when using the below command:                  jfrog config add artifactory-server --url="$ARTIFACTORY_URL" --user="$ARTIFACTORY_USER" --password="$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD" --interactive="false"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The config command tried to encrypt your Artifactory password using an incorrect URL. Typically, it happens when the user provides JFrog platform URL as Artifactory URL and the opposite.

To fix it, you have 2 options:

1. Provide Artifactory URL using the `--artifactory-url` flag:

```
jfrog config add artifactory-server --artifactory-url="$ARTIFACTORY_URL" --user="$ARTIFACTORY_USER" --password="$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD" --interactive=false
```

2. Provide the base platform URL using `--url` flag:

```
jfrog config add artifactory-server --url="$JFROG_PLATFORM_URL" --user="$ARTIFACTORY_USER" --password="$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD" --interactive=false
```

For more information see [JFrog Platform Configuration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI#JFrogCLI-JFrogPlatformConfiguration).

Comment: 1st Option Worked successfully. Thanks

Comment: doesn't fix my problem